# Java client-server application example

Tags: java, client-server

Please advice where can I see the source code example of a simple client-server application (code for both)?

Comment: We are going to need some more details or this will be closed as not a real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) is what you had in mind.

Comment: Where can I download the files for this tutorial? I have the same problem.

Comment: Didn't you see the links in the tutorial?  What more do you want?

Comment: Speaking of this example. How would a person run and test this at home without a network connection. I have used Java a lot but not for a server/client application. So how would I go about giving this a try at home.

Comment: Write a server, deploy it on your local machine.  Write a client to talk to that local server, run it and send a message.  Local loopback is sufficient.